# Unable to get the cluster and node details in Web Console agent for Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I am trying to get the node and cluster details in the Apache Ignite WebConsole. Below are the steps i have performed:
1. Download the Apache Ignite WebConsole.
2. My applications is running the ignite node as a cache layer(Ignite node started OK (id=ac87a66c,)
3. Ignite is running on Ignite discovery url 192.168.0.102:47500
4. I ran the bat file: web-console-agent.bat. But it is not able to connect to the agent  and hence the web console:

```
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,245][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Starting Apache GridGain Web Console Agent...
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,415][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher]
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,416][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Web Console Agent configuration :
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,535][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] User's security tokens             : ********************************af05
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,539][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] URI to Ignite node REST server     : http://localhost:8080
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,540][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] URI to GridGain Web Console        : https://console.gridgain.com
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,548][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Path to properties file            : default.properties
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,548][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Path to JDBC drivers folder        : C:\pluralsight\gridgain-web-console-agent-2020.03.01\jdbc-drivers
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,557][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Demo mode                          : enabled
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,560][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher]
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,621][INFO ][main][WebSocketRouter] Starting Web Console Agent...
[2020-05-26T18:05:33,635][INFO ][Connect thread][WebSocketRouter] Connecting to server: wss://console.gridgain.com
[2020-05-26T18:05:35,996][INFO ][http-client-16][WebSocketRouter] Successfully completes handshake with server
[2020-05-26T18:05:40,035][WARN ][pool-2-thread-1][ClusterHandler] Failed to connect to cluster.
[2020-05-26T18:05:40,036][WARN ][pool-2-thread-1][ClusterHandler] Check that '--node-uri' configured correctly.
[2020-05-26T18:05:40,039][WARN ][pool-2-thread-1][ClusterHandler] Ensure that cluster nodes have [ignite-rest-http] module in classpath (was copied from libs/optional to libs folder).
[2020-05-26T18:05:40,045][INFO ][pool-2-thread-1][ClustersWatcher] Failed to establish connection to node
```

Please let me know where i am missing steps

Comment: Well, do you have anything running on http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: No, i do not have anything running on http://localhost:8080

Comment: Well, you are expected to have Apache Ignite running there! Did you add ignite-rest-http to libs/ or dependencies?

Comment: No, i checked in cmd and in browser, process is not running. is there any command to run it.? also, i have copies the ignite-rest-http folder from ops to lib folder.

Comment: Did you restart ignite? Maybe it's running on a different machine?

Comment: Ok, i started ignite on my local machine through ignite.cmd command , and its getting connected.Connection successfully established to cluster with nodes: [6EC43A22].And when i start my application , which starts another Ignite node as 192.168.0.102:47500 , It is not getting connected to agent. Not visible in cmd and agent UI says that:no cluster is set

Comment: I guess your application does not have REST configured. What happens to your other Ignite node? Do you stop it? Do they form a cluster?

Comment: Hi, it might be the case. How can we check that? I am getting the below logs on running on of the engine of my application instance:
Ignite node started OK (id=756a75a4, instance name=aschauha---
Topology snapshot [ver=1, locNode=756a75a4, servers=1, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=4, offheap=1.6GB, heap=1.0GB]

Comment: This means there is only one node in a cluster. Please make sure this node has ignite-rest-http dependency in classpath

Comment: I do not have the access to the source code, so can you please tell me 
-how to check if my application is Rest enabled ? Does running http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=version on postman and seeing the result suffice?
- Does Visor tool also depends upon being ignite-rest-http enabled?

Comment: Yes, it should be enough. Visor does not use REST so it's not representative

Comment: Yes, Thanks a ton for your answer. It resolved my issue.